# How to make a script which search for a list of specific file name or file path on either of the drives in windows system

Tags: security, automation, filesystems

The main objective of the script is to check whether there are any suspicious file present on the system after a security incident. Searching it manually on multiple system is a tedious process, so it would be so helpful to guide me to make a script or let me know if something is already existed.

The program should let me input 2 list ~
filenames = []
filepaths = []

Then it should loop over my filesystem and provide me results whether these are found or not.

sample filename : LBB_PS1_obfuscated.ps1
sample filepath : C \ProgramData\DC28.tmp

Also what will be the proper way to execute this piece of script, i.e.
command prompt/shell or 
any text editor or 
in the mode of a physical drive....